# Use the VBA VariantType enum from a C# COM addin

Tags: c#, vba, enums, com, vb6

I'm migrating a VB6 **COM addin** used from **VBA**.

This addin exposes a method that returns instances of the `vbVarType` enum:

```
Function GetSomeType() As VbVarType
    GetSomeType = vbVariant
End Function
```

I'm trying to mimick it in C# and I've found the `VariantType` enum in assembly `Microsoft.VisualBasic` which seems to mirror `vbVarType`:

```
VariantType GetSomeType()
{
    return VariantType.Variant;
}
```

Unfortunately the `VariantType` enum is not **COM-visible** so I can't use it in the signature of my new COM method.

I've found a workaround by returning the value as a raw integer:

```
int GetSomeType()
{
    return (int)VariantType.Variant;
}
```

This is working fine but my COM function signature is not as clear as the VB6 one.

Is there a way to expose the `vbVarType` (and more generally any other VBA enum) from a C# COM addin?

Comment: Declare an enum in C# with values taken from `VariantType`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.interopservices.varenum%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @GSerg Thanks but I'd like to keep the same enum to be fully compatible with the old API. I've chosen an int rather than an enum because it is more "neutral".

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the suggestion. This seems an interesting middle-ground between a neutral but opaque int and an expressive but new/unknown enum.